# Enter key automation in blazor form

Tags: javascript, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-jsinterop

This is a simple Register form created using blazor with MudBlazor Framework.

[image]

following you can see the code part of the Register form.

Register. razor

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<div style="max-width: 400px;">
<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <MudCard>
        <MudCardContent>
            <MudTextField Label="First name" HelperText="Max. 8 characters"
                          @bind-Value="model.Username" For="@(() => model.Username)" @onkeydown="@keydown"/>
            <MudTextField Label="Email" Class="mt-3"
                          @bind-Value="model.Email" For="@(() => model.Email)" @onkeydown="@keydown"/>
            <MudTextField Label="Password" HelperText="Choose a strong password" Class="mt-3"
                          @bind-Value="model.Password" For="@(() => model.Password)" InputType="InputType.Password" @onkeydown="@keydown"/>
            <MudTextField Label="Password" HelperText="Repeat the password" Class="mt-3"
                          @bind-Value="model.Password2" For="@(() => model.Password2)" InputType="InputType.Password" @onkeydown="@keydown"/>
        </MudCardContent>
        <MudCardActions>
            <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto">Register</MudButton>
        </MudCardActions>


     </MudCard>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2" Align="Align.Center" Class="my-4">
            Fill out the form correctly to see the success message.
        </MudText>

        <MudExpansionPanels>
            <MudExpansionPanel Text="Show Validation Summary">
                @if (success)
                {
                    <MudText Color="Color.Success">Success</MudText>
                }
                else
                {
                    <MudText Color="@Color.Error">
                        <ValidationSummary />
                    </MudText>
                }
            </MudExpansionPanel>
        </MudExpansionPanels>
    </EditForm>
    </div>

    @code {

     [Inject] 
     protected IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; } 

    RegisterAccountForm model = new RegisterAccountForm();
    bool success;

    public class RegisterAccountForm
    {
    [Required]
    [StringLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Name length can't be more than 8.")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least 8 characters long.", MinimumLength = 8)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Compare(nameof(Password))]
    public string Password2 { get; set; }

}

private void OnValidSubmit(EditContext context)
{
    success = true;
    StateHasChanged();
}
public void keydown() 
{ 
   
        @*what should I include here??*@
    
} 

}
```

Now I am going to add the enter key automation to this form.

**requirements-**

1. After adding some value to one field and press the enter button, the
   cursor pointer should be focused on the adjacent empty field to add a
   value.

e.g.:-after add any name to the **First Name** field and press the enter key, the cursor pointer should be automatically focused on the **Email** field(if the **Email** field is empty).

2. during the above process if found one field is already filled,
   ignore it and should move on to the next field.

e.g.: if we think the situation like cursor pointer is on the **First Name** field and the **Email** field is already filled but the **password** part is not filled yet. then after pressing the enter key, instead of moving to the **Email** field, ignore the **Email** field and the cursor pointer should be focused on the **Password** field to enter the discount.

3. after adding all fields and press the enter button, first validate the data, and after all of the data should be submitted.

I need to add the above 3 parts to add to my form using blazor. if anybody knows how to do this please help me. I highly appreciate all of your help.